# Jasmine test prepends undefined on angular.copy

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, frontend

I've been testing an Angularjs frontend with `Jasmine` unit tests and I'm getting a strange error:

> Expected doStuff to have been called with [ Object({ foo: 'bar' }) ]
>
> but actual calls were [ undefined, Object({ foo: 'bar' }) ]

Unit test code:

```js
it('TestCase - test angular broadcast', function() {
    controller.anObjectInController = { foo: 'bar' };
    scope.$broadcast('doStuffBroadcast');

    expect(myService.doStuff).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ foo: 'bar' });
});
```

Actual code being tested:

```js
$scope.$on('doStuffBroadcast', function() {
    var fields = angular.copy(vm.anObjectInController);
    vm.doStuff(fields);
});
```

Why would angular prepend undefined on a simple `angular.copy`? And why is this being shown as an array anyway?

Comment: The error doesn't mean anything like that. It means that a method was called like `myService.doStuff(undefined, fields)`, not like `myService.doStuff(fields)`. It's not possible to say from the code you've posted how this could happen. This unit test is flawed because you're testing a controller and a service at the same time. This way it's not possible to say where the thing went wrong. If it's controller test, spy on `controller.doStuff` instead.

Comment: But there is no way the vm.doStuff could possibly be called with two parameters.

Comment: Tests don't lie. vm.doStuff isn't called with 2 params. myService.doStuff is. This is what I'm talking about. The test isn't isolated and it is hard to say where exactly the problem is. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem if you believe that there is something wrong with it. A plunk with Jasmine that can throw the same error will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, just to answer the earlier comment, the test is not a lie (unlike the cake).

Because a part of my code is getting loaded at a later stage coming from an external repository there is no way to control it. Therefore the solution to the problem was to create a `myExtraJQueryLibraryCodeService`
with a method `doStuff(element)` doing `element.doStuff(element)`

After the library is called it works just fine, and the `myExtraJQueryLibraryCodeService` is the only place that would be skipped from the unit tests since it's not up to us to make this external library to work.